# $(canvas).width() won't work

Tags: jquery

When using `$(canvas).width()` in my javascript file I get an error. Am I using the correct syntax when setting the variable canvas to an element `var canvas = $("#construction");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code is fine (hard to tell without error message and more context), you should be able to just do:

```
canvas.width()
```

Comment: I get this: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: This is my code: $(window).on("load", function() {
 var canvas = $("#construction");
 var c = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

 canvas.width() = $(".web-section-container").width() / 3;
});

Comment: jQuery sets width within the parens, try:

canvas.width( $(".web-section-container").width() / 3)

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: I cannt belive I missed that. Ive been working with jquery for about a year. I am just brain dead today.